# Why am I getting ERROR: Cannot read property '0' of undefined?

Tags: typescript, angular7

I don't understand why I am getting Undefined error for `tagged_Assets`
Please, can some one explain it to me, Thanks.

#### Model.ts

```
export class TaggedAssests {
   device_id: string;
   hasTag: boolean;
}
```

#### Component.ts

```
tagged_Assets: TaggedAssests[];
```

#### Usage in Component.ts

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.temp.length; i++) 
{   
        ERR-> this.tagged_Assets[i].device_id = this.temp[i].device_id;*
        this.tagged_Assets[i].hasTag = true;
}
```

Comment: try inititalizing tagged_Assets: TaggedAssests[] = [];

Comment: Did that too. After initializing it complains about `this.tagged_Assets.device_id` being undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the array :

```
tagged_Assets: TaggedAssests[] = [];
```

Or may be using ?. operator

```
this.tagged_Assets[i]?.device_id = this.temp[i].device_id;
```

Comment: Tried both. Second option give me `The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.ts(2779)`

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is that `this.tagged_Assets` is `undefined`, so you cannot access the property `device_id`

you can solve that by initializing `this.tagged_Assets = []` any modifying your loop block to

```
this.tagged_Assets[i] =  {
    device_id: this.temp[i].device_id,
    hasTag: true
}
```

Comment: No Change. Same Error.

Comment: @yodellingbutters okay, so in which context are you using that loop. perhaps in a function that is called somewhere else? Cause that would potentionally screw with your `this`

Comment: It's been called when the page loads inside `ngOnInit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Init - `tagged_Assets: TaggedAssests[] = [];`

And use it like this -

```
this.tagged_Assets[i] =  {
   device_id: this.temp[i].device_id,
   hasTag: true
}
```